# cant access method name from variable

Tags: codeigniter, methods

I m trying to use the method name from variable as below but however can't getting success in it. code is as below

```
$function_name = $this->input->post('class_name');
if(method_exists($this, $function_name))
    {
        $foo = $this;
        $foo->$function_name();
    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
```

But keep getting the error of Method name must be a string

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method trialdemo::() in D:\xampp\htdocs\trialdemo\application\controllers\trialdemoapp.php on line 38
```

Comment: In post you are sending 'class_name' and checking for method? is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(method_exists($this, $function_name))
    {
        call_user_func($function_name);
    }
    else
    ...
```

In addition to [call_user_func](http://www.php.net/call_user_func) you might want to read about [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [is_callable](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php).